# How do I toggle multiple images with radio buttons in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, button, radio-button, dreamweaver

I'm trying to create an HTML page that has a form. I'm trying to make it so that when you click the following radio buttons:

(Radio button) Red
(Radio button) Blue
(Radio button) Green
(Radio button) White
(Radio button) Black

They load up the following images

```
Red.png  
Blue.png  
Green.png   
White.png  
Black.png
```

I've been looking on other websites for almost 3 hours and would really appreciate any help I can get! I understand that this requires HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: Not Java, but JavaScript. That will improve your search results immensely.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript, not Java :)

I would do this by adding an `onclick` attribute to those `<input>` tags, the value of the `onclick` attribute would be some JavaScript code that would change the `src` of that image (probably getting the image's DOM node using `document.getElementById("ID");` )

Also, a great place to learn about JavaScript is at [w3schools](http://w3schools.com/js/default.asp)!

Comment: Watch out with w3schools. They're not affiliated with the w3c and the instruction can be detrimental at times http://w3fools.com/. I recommend grabbing a good book if someone want's to get serious with Javascript.

Comment: @BlakeTaylor, w3schools is still a good resource, 99% of their material is correct (w3fools seems to be nitpicking), it is worded well for beginners, and it conveys the basic concepts well.

Comment: Fair point, however, nitpicking, I'd argue, it the primary difference between ie and chrome. I'll agree they're a useful resource for beginners and even experienced, but all the more reason to hold them to strict educational standards. I hope no offense was taken, the w3fools.com url is, perhaps, in this context, unfortunately presuming.